# Convert TXT to CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv

I would like to convert it into a csv file with header showing Issue number and the row below will be the error name and its directory at the column beside.

I have a text file called bucket like this:

-------------NEW-------------------

Issue 1

UVM_FATAL :    1

1 test(s) failed with similar error:

/nfs/disks/ben/rundir/test534

-------------NEW-------------------

Issue 2

benshi:  4356175.000 ns register error

3 test(s) failed with similar error:

/nfs/disks/ben/rundir/test234

/nfs/disks/ben/rundir/test321

/nfs/disks/ben/rundir/test123

So far this is what I tried, but it doesn't work. Anyone know how to do this?By the way, the Issue wasnt only limited to Issue 1 and 2, it can be going up to infinity depends on the "bucket" text file.

```
bucket = "/nfs/disks/ben/bucket"
inputfile = open(bucket,"r")
bucketreading = inputfile.readlines()
for presence_of_new in bucketreading:
    find_presence_of_new = re.search(r"-------------NEW-------------------",presence_of_new,re.M|re.I)  
    if presence_of_new != 0:
    print "I found NEW!"
    for error_name in bucketreading :
      find_error_name = re.search(r"UVM_FATAL :",error_name,re.M|re.I)
      if find_error_name != 0:
          print_output_to_outfile = open(outfile,"w")
          print_output_to_outfile.writelines(error_name) 
          print_output_to_outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. The re.search returns an object if the pattern match, otherwise returns None, so you dont need to compare with 0.

```
bucket = r"/nfs/disks/ben/bucket"
    inputfile = open(bucket, "r")
    bucketreading = inputfile.readlines()
    for presence_of_new in bucketreading:
        find_presence_of_new = re.search(r"-------------NEW-------------------", presence_of_new, re.M | re.I)
        if find_presence_of_new:
            print("I found NEW!")
        for error_name in bucketreading:
            find_error_name = re.search(r"UVM_FATAL :", error_name, re.M | re.I)
            if find_error_name:
                print_output_to_outfile = open(outfile, "w")
                print_output_to_outfile.writelines(error_name)
                print_output_to_outfile.close()
```